# How to handle the logout process in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, logout

I am using j meter to run the concurrent users.After login the application, I searched the files and finally logout from the application.I don't know to handle the logout process.Currently I created the 100 users.

- 100 users are logged into the application.
- 100 users are searched something.
- 100 users are needed to sign out.

How to do the third step. When I was recording the logout,there is no process are recorded.Could you please tell me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Usually logout is:

1. Associated with the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Assumes clearing session data so if you have > 1 Loop on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level and using one of the following (or both):

   - [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)
   - [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar)

   Make sure you have `Clear xxx on each iteration` box checked

Answer (score 0):

Logging out is a call just like any other- and it will be specific to your site. If you closed a browser tab or window, it's possible that you didn't actually log out from your site. It's also possible if you stopped recording too soon that you simply didn't record it.

I suggest manually adding it. You'll have to go into your Browser's Network Debugger to find the actual call that you're looking for, and then recreate it in JMeter.